# Asp.net MVC ModelState.Isvalid returning false for Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, modelstate

I'm watching this [ASP.NET MVC course](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-aspnet-mvc-5-course/). I have a `customer` `model` with these following attribute.

```
public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]        
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public bool IsSubscribedToNewsLetter { get; set; }


    public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Membership Type")]
    public byte? MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Note thate the Id has no `Required` data annotation. But in my database, the Id is primary key and Identity is true for the column.

There is a `ViewModel` consisting `Customer` and `MembershipType` models.

```
    public class CustomerFormViewModel {
        public IEnumerable<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a View that creates `new Customer` with `Name`, `DateOfBirth`, `MembershipType` and `IsSubscribedToNewsLetter` fields. It takes the `CustomerFormViewModel`.

```
@using Vidly.Models
@model Vidly.ViewModel.CustomerFormViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Customer")) {
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name,new{@class="control-label"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Customer.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "control-label"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.DateOfBirth,"{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId, new { @class = "control-label"})
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId,new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes,"Id","Name"), "Select Membership Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
    
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter) Subscribed To Newsletter?
        </label>

    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Customer.Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Here is my `Save` controller:

```
    public ActionResult Save(Customer customer) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel {
                Customer = customer,
                MembershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList()
            };
            return View("CustomerForm", viewModel);
        }
        if (customer.Id == 0 || customer.Id==null) {
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        }
        else {
            var CustomerInDb = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);
            CustomerInDb.Name = customer.Name;
            CustomerInDb.DateOfBirth = customer.DateOfBirth;
            CustomerInDb.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter;
            CustomerInDb.MembershipTypeId = customer.MembershipTypeId;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
    }
```

When I fill the `CustomerForm` view and click the submit button, the `ModelState.Isvalid()` method always comes false; resulting the first `if statement` of the `Save` method true. So I can't store any new customer.

I tried to `debug` the application by putting `breakpoint` on `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` and saw that the `Id` field is creating a error(saying "The Id field is required"). Why is it saying that `Id` is required when it isn't? Does the `ModelState.IsValid` method check the model at database level? I don't think so.

If I change the `Customer` model's `Id` property like this:`public int? Id { get; set; }` and change the if statement by this,`if ((!ModelState.IsValid) && (customer.Id==null) )` the application works fine.

Is there any other solution of this `Id` problem?

Comment: It**is** required. Its an `int` and an `int` cannot be `null`. But view models do not contain data models, especially for editing data. The contain only the properties of the data model that you need in the view. Refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 6):

I watched the same course and I am guessing the author updated since you watched it, as he demonstrated this exact type of issue.  The issue is that when returning the View Model to the View on the New Action, the Customer property is not initialized so the Id is null hence the ModelState failure when trying to Save

Just change as below, so that when setting the viewModel, you initialize the Customer and the Id is then 0:

```
 public ActionResult New()
    {
        var memberShipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList();

        var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel
        {
            Customer = new Customer(),
            MembershipTypes = memberShipTypes
        };

        return View("CustomerForm", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Exactly 
Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Had a heck of a time with this, and created a workaround, but it seems that Mosh addresses this in a later section where he sets up the Movie Form.

https://codewithmosh.com/courses/222293/lectures/3684111

The short answer is to add `@Html.Hidden("Movie.Id", (Model.Movie != null) ? Model.Movie.Id : 0)` to the MovieForm.cshtml.

He then describes a way to avoid hard-coding "Movie.Id" into the view (see https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vidly-mvc-5/commit/e5b994581931a079ad87418ddcf9338e808bd821#diff-e94a8dc96403203b00e58238bb80101c )

Answer (score 0):

This is just a rough draft as I don't have access to VS right now. Anyway, modify your Save action like so:

```
public ActionResult Save(CustomerFormViewModel customerVM) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View(customerVM);
    }
    if (customer.Id == 0) {
        _context.Customers.Add(customerVM.Customer);
    }
    else {
        var CustomerInDb = _context.Customers.Find(customerVM.Customer.Id);
        CustomerInDb.Name = customer.Name;
        CustomerInDb.DateOfBirth = customer.DateOfBirth;
        CustomerInDb.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter;
        CustomerInDb.MembershipTypeId = customer.MembershipTypeId;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
}
```

Oh and you can remove the following from the view since this is for create page:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Customer.Id)
```

Comment: I can't use the `CustomerFormViewModel` for several reasons. And even if I did, I highly doubt that it would solve my problem.

Comment: It should work. I have been working with ASP.NET MVC for a while now and this usually works for me (of course with some debugging). Anyway, you have found solution to your problem with minimal code changes so good for you.

Answer (score 0):

hey change Id to CustomerId in model class.
i think just 'Id' may be treated as Primary Key of that model class.

Comment: I did that on purpose, because I'm using `code first` migration with that model class..

Answer (score 0):

we are doing the same course and i ran into the exact same problem lol.
i found a pretty nice workaround in my opinion.

just add these lines of code in the `CustomerFormView`.
instead of 
`@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Customer.Id)`

Add:

```
 {
        if (Model.Customer == null)
        {
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Customer_Id" name="Customer.Id" type="hidden" value="0" />
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.Id)
        }
    }
```

for some reason i saw that when i try to add a new customer , the value of id is an empty string instead of zero.
therefore i changed it to zero manually in case the Customer object is null 
(which will always be the case when adding a new customer.) 
and it works fine for me.

let me know if you think this solution is problematic..

BTW  Regarding your question : "the Id field is creating a error(saying "The Id field is required"). Why is it saying that Id is required when it isn't?"

Int data type is non nullable therefore it is implicitly required..same as the MembershipId (byte data type that doesnt have the `[Required]` annotation.)

Answer (score 0):

I am also going through this course. i have got a same issue. Add this line in the customerviewform

```
if (Model.Customers !=null)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customers.Id)
    }
```

Why i have add because while hiddenfor which it is used for editing purpose if you remove also it will be problem. So add this line it will we be work and in customer model add public int? Membershiptype. And another thing while adding a new customer if you got error at dropdownlist then add this line before validation area return

```
 customer.MembershipTypes = _Context.MembershipTypeTableset.ToList(); add this line before     View("CustomerForm", viewModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is taken from Mosh Hamedani's MVC 5 course. He explained the Customer Id issue in the chapter 55. This can be resolved by passing a new customer() object in New method while creating a CustomerFormViewModel.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the problem is that the `Id` field is marked as an `int` and not `int?`. Putting a variable as `int` the Model automatically assumes there's going to be a value for this property since it's not marked `nullable`.

Try marking the `Id` Property is `int?` and see if the results are what you expect or not.

Comment: I already tried your suggestion and included it in my question. I was asking for any different solution. Perhaps you didn't fully read the question.

Comment: Hi @AhashanAlamSojib, I fully understand what you are asking but please note that it is not logical to have `Id` as Identity in Db and make it nullable in the model. If I was to make a solution, I would keep `Id = 0` by default when adding a new Customer and then once I have the new Customer I would get the ID (which is delivered by the DAO) and save it in my model. After `_context.SaveChanges()` You can do `customer.Id = CustomerInDb.Id`

Answer (score -1):

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883630/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-isvalid-returning-false) question, I made a workaround of my problem. I just disabled my `Id` error in `ModelState` at the very beginning of `Save` action.

```
public ActionResult Save(Customer customer) {
    ModelState["customer.Id"].Errors.Clear();
    if ((!ModelState.IsValid) ) {
        var viewModel = new CustomerFormViewModel {
            Customer = customer,
            MembershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList()
        };
        return View("CustomerForm", viewModel);
    }
    if (customer.Id == 0) {
        _context.Customers.Add(customer);
    }
    else {
        var CustomerInDb = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);
        CustomerInDb.Name = customer.Name;
        CustomerInDb.DateOfBirth = customer.DateOfBirth;
        CustomerInDb.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter;
        CustomerInDb.MembershipTypeId = customer.MembershipTypeId;
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customer");
}
```

Now my Application works fine.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not ideal. It's a quick and dirty way of dealing with the problem.

Comment: @corix010 I used dirty coding because I know that the `Id` field will not bother with any other errors. I'm certain of it. So it seemed legit to cut the root.